# Do I need to use nginx or Apache to use Lets Encrypt?

Tags: apache, encryption, nginx, go, lets-encrypt

I have a *really* simple API based on golang that just listens at a path and responds accordingly with a database insert.

I want to serve it over TLS/https using Lets Encrypt, but all the tutorials seem to indicate use of Apache or nginx as a requirement.

I like keeping my server really light and haven't seen any need to introduce the overhead of these web servers (it's definitely not a full fledged website) and over http my go implementation works well.

Is it possible to install it without Apache or nginx?

Comment: I suggest to use nginx or apache, leave the tls/https/cert work to deploy team, and let developers focus on business.

Answer (score 4):

No, you do not need to use Apache/Nginx, Go handles TLS just fine.

Check [http.ListenAndServeTLS](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServeTLS)

Example:

```
➜ sudo letsencrypt certonly --standalone --agree-tos --email you@email.com -d domain1.com [-d domain2.com, etc..]
➜ sudo cat /etc/letsencrypt/archive/domain1.com/fullchain1.pem > cert.pem
➜ sudo cat /etc/letsencrypt/archive/domain1.com/privkey1.pem > key.pem 

➜ cat main.go
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w.Write([]byte("This is an example server.\n"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Printf("About to listen on 10443. Go to https://domain1.com:10443/")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":10443", "cert.pem", "key.pem", nil))
}
```

Note that if you want your go server to listen on port 443 (default https port), you will either have to run it as root or use systemd to pass it the port.

Example of running on port 443:

1. Change the code to `log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "cert.pem", "key.pem", nil))`
2. `go build`
3. `sudo ./your-package-name`
4. or if you don't want to run as root, you will have to chown cert.pem/key.pem as your user then run `setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep your-package-name` then you will be able to listen on port 443/80 as a user.

More details about using setcap: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NonRootPortBinding

Comment: Awesome! Do you know of a tutorial that would show me how to set up Let's Encrypt without appache/nginx then? Their github and most sites seem to only explain in the context of those two

Comment: how do I go about listening on port 80 or 443 so that it's available at /?

Comment: `go build && sudo ./your-service`, I'll add it to the post.

Comment: Wouldn't it always be running as root then? Is that bad?

Comment: not "bad", depends on your setup, you can always copy the certificate and chown it to your user then setcap, I'll add an example.

Comment: Last question! In the above example you seemingly cat the cert files to the directory of your go program. Is this secure? Is this just your home directory? Is it okay to have certs there? I thought they had to be in a secure location.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110406/discussion-between-oneofone-and-mickdoe).